# Adding theme support for a custom header image

Tags: php, custom-header, add-theme-support

I'm using `add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $defaults );` to support custom header images in my theme. The `$defaults` are described in the [Custom Headers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers) article

```
$defaults = array(
    'default-image'          => '',
    'random-default'         => false,
    'width'                  => 0,
    'height'                 => 0,
    'flex-height'            => false,
    'flex-width'             => false,
    'default-text-color'     => '',
    'header-text'            => true,
    'uploads'                => true,
    'wp-head-callback'       => '',
    'admin-head-callback'    => '',
    'admin-preview-callback' => '',
);
```

There is no explanation in the Codex for the following. What do they mean?

- wp-head-callback
- admin-head-callback
- admin-preview-callback

Answer (score 0):

Those are name of callback function which would be enabled for custom header.

For example: if `custom_function` is assigned to 'wp-head-callback' then, there would be an action call like:

`add_action('wp_head','custom_function')`

`custom_function` is the function you need to define.

Comment: Hi @Nilambar - thanks, I am aware of how callbacks work. I should have asked what is the point of having these callbacks? What should these callbacks actually do?

Comment: ok :-). That is the feature given by WP for us to extend to our imagination. Lets say, we want to animate or ease the image on hover of header image, then those scripts could be placed in the callback function. Just my poor imagination. :D

Comment: Why would I use `wp-head-callback` over `admin-head-callback` or `admin-preview-callback`? What's the difference?

Comment: `wp_head` is related with frontend template whereas `admin_head` is for admin side. They are pretty different.